# Amortized complexity of viterbi algorithm for first-order HMM

Tags: self-study, hidden-markov-model, viterbi-algorithm

The Viterbi algorithm is a dynamic programming algorithm for obtaining the maximum a posteriori probability estimate of the most likely sequence of hidden states—called the Viterbi path—that results in a sequence of observed events, especially in the context of Markov information sources and hidden Markov models (HMM). See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm).

Given a first order Viterbi algorithm, please try to prove the amortized complexity of viterbi algorithm is O(T $\times(|S|+|E|)$) using amortized analysis, where HMM with state space S, sequence length T, E is the number of state transition edges. It is also stated in [Viterbi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm).

Comment: Welcome to CV, Peter.  Could you please be more specific than "how about"?  What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Solved, I have removed this part, leaving the first order one as defined in the wiki page. Thanks! @whuber